# como direcionar uma pagina sincronamente no nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

boa tarde eu possuo uma pagina chamada index.js na pasta route do nodejs express.

quando a pagina pendingAprovals for chamada eu gostaria que a index chamasse um webservice para enviar um JSON para a pendingAprovals, porem o node trata o codigo assincrono fazendo com que a variavel nao seja preenchida.

abaixo o codigo que tenho:

index.js

```js
var options = {
    host: 'localHost',
    port: 7001,
    path: 'meuWebService/meuMetodo',
    mothod: 'GET',
    header: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
};
var list =
    http.request(options, function(res) {
        var body = "";
        res.setEncoding('utf-8');
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function() {
            list = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(body));
        });
    });

list.end();
```

Comment: `    mothod: 'GET',` isto é erro de copy-paste ou é o que tens nas options, mesmo? tenta trocar por `method: 'GET'`

Comment: ajustei mas mesmo assim nao funciona de forma sincrona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode mandar a resposta dentro do callback do request

```js
function performRequest(callback){
  http.request(options, function(res) {
    var body = "";
    res.setEncoding('utf-8');
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
      body += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
      callback(body);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

uma outra forma que encontrei para fazer isso foi executar a chamada da seguinte maneira no arquivo de rotas. ( que no meu caso era index.js )

```
router.get('/solicitacoes', function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.session.name) {
        return res.redirect('/');
    }
    var endereco = 'MeuWebService/MetodoGet'
    var name = req.session.name;
    request(endereco, (err, response, body) => {
        if (!err && response.statusCode == 200) {
            res.render('solicitacoes', {
                title: 'MeuTitulo',
                page: 'solicitacoes',
                list: JSON.parse(body),
                user: name,
                Config: config,
                modalData: ""
            });
        }
    });
});
```

uma parte importante foi fazer esse JSON.parse(body) sem esse parse nao funciona.